# Georgi's "Lie Algebras in Particle Physics" Theorem 1.2 proof

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

In Georgi's "Lie Algebras in Particle Physics", Theorem 1.2 reads

> Every representation of a finite group is completely reducible.

The proof that follows contains the following lines

> If it is reducible, $\exists$ a projector $P$ such that $PD(g)P = D(g)P \forall g \in G$. Taking the adjoint gives $PD(g)^\dagger P = P D(g)^\dagger \forall g \in G$.

What happened to $P^\dagger$? Are the projectors self-adjoint? Why?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1124423/683578